# Is there a way to simplify summed integrals (with the same integrand but different limits) into one integral?

Tags: calculus, fourier-transform

I was trying to compute the Fourier Transform of [this trapezium shape (starting at the origin)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YE2QN.png), defined by the following piecewise function:

$S(t<0)=0$

$S(0<t\leq T_R)=\frac{H}{T_R}t$

$S(T_R<t\leq T-T_R)=H$

$S(T-T_R<t\leq T)=-\frac{H}{T_R}t+\frac{HT}{T_R}$

$S(t>T)=0$

The Fourier Transform could be defined as (where j is the imaginary number):

$
S(\omega)=
(\int_{0}^{T_R}{\frac{H}{T_R}te^{-j\omega t}dt}
-\int_{T-T_R}^{T}{\frac{H}{T_R}te^{-j\omega t}dt})
+\int_{T_R}^{T-T_R}{He^{-j\omega t}dt}
+\int_{T-T_R}^{T}{\frac{HT}{T_R}e^{-j\omega t}dt}
$

To simplify this expression, is it possible to combine the summed integrals in the brackets, since they have the same integrand but different limits.

***edit:***

**To avoid confusion, from this point on, the trapezium height will be defined as h**

Starting with the input of @John Wayland Bales in the comments, I have rewritten the function S(t) in terms of Heaviside step functions $(H(t))$ and used that to simplify to only 3 integrals.

$S(t)=\frac{h}{T_R}[H(t)t-H(t-T_R)(t-T_R)-H(t-(T-T_R))(t-(T-T_R))+H(t-T)(t-T)]$

$
\frac{T_R}{h}S(\omega)=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{H(t)t*e^{-j\omega t}dt}-
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{H(t-T_R)(t-T_R)*e^{-j\omega t}dt}-
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{H(t-(T-T_R))(t-(T-T_R))*e^{-j\omega t}dt}+
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{H(t-T)(t-T)*e^{-j\omega t}dt}
$

Using the time shift theorem, where appropriate:

$
\frac{T_R}{h}S(\omega)=
\int_{0}^{\infty}{t*e^{-j\omega t}dt}-
e^{-j\omega T_R}*\int_{0}^{\infty}{(t-T_R)*e^{-j\omega t}dt}-
e^{-j\omega (T-T_R)}*\int_{0}^{\infty}{(t-(T-T_R))*e^{-j\omega t}dt}+
e^{-j\omega T}*\int_{0}^{\infty}{(t-T)*e^{-j\omega t}dt}
$

$
\frac{T_R}{h}S(\omega)=
\int_{0}^{\infty}{t*e^{-j\omega t}dt}-
e^{-j\omega T_R}*\int_{0}^{\infty}{t*e^{-j\omega t}dt}+
e^{-j\omega T_R}*\int_{0}^{\infty}{T_R*e^{-j\omega t}dt}-
e^{-j\omega (T-T_R)}*\int_{0}^{\infty}{t*e^{-j\omega t}dt}+
e^{-j\omega (T-T_R)}*\int_{0}^{\infty}{T*e^{-j\omega t}dt}-
e^{-j\omega (T-T_R)}*\int_{0}^{\infty}{T_R*e^{-j\omega t}dt}+
e^{-j\omega T}*\int_{0}^{\infty}{t*e^{-j\omega t}dt}-
e^{-j\omega T}*\int_{0}^{\infty}{T*e^{-j\omega t}dt}
$

$
\frac{T_R}{h}S(\omega)=\\
[1+e^{-j\omega T}-e^{-j\omega T_R}-e^{-j\omega (T-T_R)}]
\int_{0}^{\infty}{t*e^{-j\omega t}dt}\\
+[e^{-j\omega T_R}-e^{-j\omega (T-T_R)}]
\int_{0}^{\infty}{T_R*e^{-j\omega t}dt}\\
+[e^{-j\omega (T-T_R)}-e^{-j\omega T}]
\int_{0}^{\infty}{T*e^{-j\omega t}dt}
$

Comment: Yes, provided that you re-write the piecewise function in terms of the unit step function.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales you mean something like: $S(t) = H(t)*\frac{Ht}{T_R} + H(t - T_R)*(H-\frac{Ht}{T_R}) + ...$

Comment: Using $U(t)=0$ for $t<0$ and $U(t)=1$ for $t>0$, then $U(t-a)=0$ for $t<a$ and $U(t-a)=1$ for $t>a$. You can use $(U(t-T_R), U(t-(T-T_R))$ etc. to rewrite the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using unit step functions you can re-write the function as follows.

$$ S(t)=\frac{H}{T_R}[t-(t-T_R)U(t-T_R)-(t-(T-T_R))U(t-(T-T_R))+(t-T)U(t-T) ] $$